# Write examples to the same TFRecord file in parallel

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a process that reads URIs of CSV files located in cloud storage, serializes the data (one file is an "example" in `tensorflow` speak), and writes them to the same TFRecord file.

The process is very slow and I would like to parallelize the writing using python multiprocessing. I've searched high and low and tried multiple implementations to no avail. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910590/how-to-bulk-write-tfrecords) is very similar to mine, but the question is never really answered.

This is the closest I've come (unfortunately, I can't really provide a replicable example due to the read from cloud storage):

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
import tensorflow as TF


TFR_PATH = "./tfr.tfrecord"
BANDS = ["B2", "B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B8A","B11","B12"]

def write_tfrecord(tfr_path, df_list, bands):
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(tfr_path) as writer: 
        for _, grp in df_list:
            band_data = {b: [] for b in bands}
            for i, row in grp.iterrows():
                try:
                    df = pd.read_csv(row['uri'])
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    continue
                df = prepare_df(df, bands)
                label = row['FS_crop'].encode()
                for b in bands:
                    band_data[b].append(list(df[b].astype('Int64')))

            # pad to same length and flatten
            mlen = max([len(j) for j in band_data[list(band_data.keys())[0]]])
            npx = len(band_data[list(band_data.keys())[0]])
            flat_band_data = {k: [] for k in band_data}
            for k,v in band_data.items(): # for each band
                for b in v:
                    flat_band_data[k].extend(b + [0] * int(mlen - len(b)))

            example_proto = serialize_example(npx, flat_band_data, label)
            writer.write(example_proto)

# List of grouped DF object, may be 1000's long
gqdf = list(qdf.groupby("field_centroid_str"))

n = 100 #Groups of files to write 
processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=write_tfrecord, args=(TFR_PATH, gqdf[i:i+n], BANDS)) for i in range(0, len(gqdf), n)]

for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

p.close()
```

This processes will finish, but when I go to read a record, I like so:

```
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(TFR_PATH)
for raw_record in raw_dataset.take(10):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
    print(example)
```

I always end up with a corrupted data error `DataLossError: corrupted record at 7462 [Op:IteratorGetNext]`

Any ideas on the correct approach for doing something like this? I've tried using `Pool` instead of `Process`, but the `tf.io.TFRecordWriter` can't be pickled, so it doesn't work.

Comment: How have you solved it? Did you end up using multiprocessing?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar use case. The core issue is that the record writer isn't process-safe. There are two bottlenecks - serializing the data and writing to the output. My solution here was to use multiprocessing (ex. a pool) to serialize the data in parallel. Each worker communicates the serialized data to a single consumer process using a queue. The consumer simply pulls off the queue and writes sequentially. If this is now the bottleneck, you could have multiple record writers write to different files.